# Protractor spec file path not working

Tags: javascript, protractor

I'm new to using Protractor, and i've gotten everything set up follow the tutorial on github. I was able to successfully complete the entire tutorial but now that i've tried to use it on my actual code i'm having a problem.
I can only call the spec.js file if it's within the same folder as the conf.js file.

For example:

```
 specs : [ '/web-app/test/unit/jasmine/spec.js' ],
```

The conf.js file is in a separate folder and this doesn't work but if I move the spec.js to the same folder as conf.js then it works. Like so:

```
specs : [ 'spec.js' ],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should refer to test files relative to the conf.js file. So when you conf.js file is in the root folder and your testcases are in the folder test/e2e/ it should be something like this:

```
specs : [ 'test/e2e/spec.js' ],
```

It think it's best to group test specifications by functionality and name the spec files accordingly, like someFunctionalitySpec.js. The spec include can then be:

```
specs : [ 'test/e2e/*Spec.js' ],
```

And all testscases that end with Spec.js are included.